# What does this crossed-note notation mean?

Tags: theory, notation

What does this notation mean?

[image: Notation]

It is in 5/8 time. Is it some sort of a performance direction?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site isn't about completing someone's homework.

Comment: @Tim We don't have a rule against homework.  It's one thing if it's low quality in which case we treat it like any other post: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/a/2148/28 and http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/304/28

Comment: How about a dupe: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7527/four-dots-over-tremolo-minim-half-note-with-slash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The beam fragments drawn through stems mean that each of the 8th notes should be divided into two 16th notes.

This has nothing to do with the 5/8 time, it's simply a shorthand notation to save writing a lot of note heads, particularly for dense tremolos.